# What is the command to show Jupyter Notebook version installed on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I am running Ubuntu 17.10. 
I want to discover which version of Jupyter Notebook I am running using terminal commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Jupyter documentation](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab) it is

```
jupyter notebook --version
```

Answer (score 1):

On your terminal -

`jupyter --version`